# Ошибки при установке двух операционных систем Windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-7

На компьютере пол года стояла Windows 7_32. В качестве второй операционной системы, потребовалось установить Windows 10_64. Для этого был создан новый раздел диска при установке (раздел E по отношению к Win7 или раздел C по отношению к Win10). Установка прошла без проблем, и всё стабильно работало ещё пару месяцев.

Недавно появилась проблема постоянного сканирования жёсткого диска компьютера при запуске любой из систем на наличие ошибок. Проверил ЖД при помощи сторонних утилит (в частности Acronis Disk Director Suite) - всё в порядке.

Ещё один важный момент - **пути на ярлыках**. Например: если запустить Win10 и попасть в каталог рабочего стола Win7, то можно заметить, что путь к файлам Win7 прописан через `C:\`, хотя должен быть точно не этот диск (т.к. на диске `C` в данный момент находятся файлы Win10).

В моём случае получается такая чехарда:

- **Для ОС Win7** `C:\` - файлы windows7, `D:\` - файлы и папки общего назначения, `E:\` - файлы windows10.
- **Для ОС Win10** `C:\` - файлы windows10, `D:\` - файлы windows7, `E:\` - файлы и папки общего назначения.

  Помогите в решении данной проблемы без переустановки систем, т.к. в данный момент они активно используются.

*P.S.* сколь бы иронично это не звучало, но я уверен в правильности установки Win10.

Comment: проверьте диск программой mhdd из-под DOS - вероятно с ним проблемы

Comment: А вам точно нужно при работе в той или иной системе иметь доступ к диску второй системы? Если нет, то имеет смысл убрать соответствующие назначения букв диска.

Comment: @Yaant Да, нужен полный доступ ко всем разделам ЖД в системе.